# Is every square matrix a tensor of 2nd order?

Tags: matrices, tensors

Is every square matrix a second order tensor? If not, what is an example of a square matrix, which is not a tensor? How can I prove that a matrix is in fact a tensor?

Comment: instead of order we use rank, matrices are rank-two tensors, any matrix is one of them

Comment: "The total number of indices required to uniquely select each component is equal to the dimension of the array, and is called the order, degree or rank of the tensor." (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multidimensional_arrays). But searching through the article the term "order" seems to be the most used one.